# select updated_dates which are not between started_date and stopped_date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table one contains updated_at (can be more than one row) datetime And second contains started_date and stopped_date(one or more records).

I want select updated_at date which should not in between started_date and stopped_date.

Thanks in advance.

I saw the other Question "Check overlap of date ranges in MySQL".

But this not what I want.

user_location

```
+---+-----+-----+---------------------+
|id | lat | lon | updated_date        |
+---+-----+-----+---------------------+
| 1 |16.45|75.45|2018-01-09 12:50:57  |
| 2 |16.85|75.15|2018-01-09 12:53:45  |
| 3 |16.78|75.25|2018-01-09 12:55:48  |
| 4 |16.43|75.35|2018-01-09 13:57:35  |
| 5 |16.48|75.47|2018-01-09 14:59:30  |
| 6 |16.49|75.49|2018-01-10 05:59:58  |
| 7 |16.50|75.50|2018-01-10 07:35:15  |
+---+-----+-----+---------------------+
```

location_blocked_datetime

```
+---+--------------------+---------------------+
|id |     start_date     |  stopped_date       |
+---+--------------------+---------------------+
| 1 |2018-01-09 05:55:48 | 2018-01-09 07:55:48 |
| 2 |2018-01-09 12:51:48 | 2018-01-09 12:56:48 |
| 3 |2018-01-10 04:30:48 | 2018-01-04 06:55:48 |
+---+--------------------+---------------------+
```

I want select location from user_location table where updated_date should not be there in start_date and stopped_date.start_date and stopped dates are not fixed and contain more than 1 records

The result of above query should look like this:-

If I want to select locations On 2018-01-09

Result Of Above Query

```
+---+-----+-----+---------------------+
|id | lat | lon | updated_date        |
+---+-----+-----+---------------------+
| 1 |16.45|75.45|2018-01-09 12:50:57  |
| 2 |16.43|75.35|2018-01-09 13:57:35  |
| 3 |16.48|75.47|2018-01-09 14:59:30  |
+---+-----+-----+---------------------+
```

Comment: What does id represent in the above result set?

Comment: Its from user_location table and its primary key

Comment: So I get this right, that the tables are not actually connected and you want to get the records where updated_date is not between *any* start_date - stopped_date range?

Comment: Er, that makes no sense to me

Comment: @Strawberry My sentence or OP's question?

Comment: @fancypants OP's last comment

Answer (score 0):

> So I get this right, that the tables are not actually connected and you want to get the records where updated_date is not between any start_date - stopped_date range?

If so, then use `not exists` like this:

```
SELECT 
l.*
FROM
user_location l
WHERE DATE(l.updated_date) = '2018-01-09'
and not exists (select 1 from location_blocked_datetime
               where l.updated_date between start_date and stopped_date)

| id | lat | lon |        updated_date |
|----|-----|-----|---------------------|
|  1 |  16 |  75 | 2018-01-09 12:50:57 |
|  4 |  16 |  75 | 2018-01-09 13:57:35 |
|  5 |  16 |  75 | 2018-01-09 14:59:30 |
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e25f9/5/0)